# Is the closed unit disk a regular surface?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, surfaces, submanifold

> A set $S \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is a regular surface iff, for every
> point $p$ in $S$ there is a function $\phi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to W = V \cap S$, called a parametrization of $p$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $V$ is open in
> $\mathbb{R^3}$, satisfying
>
> 1 - $\phi$ is $C^\infty$
>
> 2 - $\phi$ is a homeomorphism
>
> 3 - For every
> $X \in U$, the differential $dq_X: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ is
> injective.

I've read the following solution:

> Consider $D = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |(x, y)| \leq 1 \land z = 0\}$.
> Assume, for contradiction, that $D$ is a regular surface. Let $p \in D$ with $|p| = 1$. Take a parametrization $\phi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to W \subset D$ of $p$.
> Without loss of generality, assume $\frac{\partial (x, y)}{\partial(u, v)} \neq 0$. Consider $\pi \circ \phi: U \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where
> $\pi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $(x, y, z) = (x, y)$.
>
> By the inverse function theorem, there are neighborhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $q = \phi^{-1}(p)$ and $\pi(p)$ respectively, such that $\psi = (\pi \circ \phi)|V_1: V_1 \to V_2$ is a homeomorphism. Thus, $D$ cannot be a regular surface because $V_2$ is
> not an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

But it seems to me that there is no contradiction in $\psi(V_1) = V_2$ unless you use a stronger argument, such as the theorem of [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). So, I don't know how to prove that $D$ is not a regular surface, and the proof above seems wrong. Do you have any suggestions on how to prove it without appealing to algebraic topology?

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: @ArcticChar the question in the title "Is the closed unit disk a regular surface?"

Comment: @TedShifrin, I've edited the definition of $D$ it should make sense now.

Comment: Couple of suggestions. Your question in the title itself is fine, but one other thing to keep in mind from our guidelines on [the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): *Your question should be clear without the title...  The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title*.

Comment: Also, it's hard to tell exactly what is being contradicted here, because you have not included the definition of a *regular surface*. After including that definition, you should say more clearly where you think the contradiction lies.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've made the changes you've pointed out

Comment: With differentiability and the Inverse Function Theorem, invariance of domain drops out immediately. A diffeomorphism in this setting automatically maps an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ to an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin How so? (The text where the question came from, Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, does not assume the theorem of invariance of domain as given).

Comment: Nor should it. Let's talk about $\Bbb H^2 = \{(x,y): y\ge 0\}\subset\Bbb R^2$. Why is it not a regular surface? Suppose $\phi\colon U\to V$ is a diffeomorphism of a neighborhood of $0\in\Bbb H$ to a neighborhood of $0\in V\subset\Bbb R^2$. Then the Inverse Function Theorem tells you that $\phi^{-1}$ maps a neighborhood of $0\in\Bbb R^2$ to an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, but $U\subset\Bbb H^2$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin does the inverse function theorem apply when U is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It does, because what it means for $\phi$ to be smooth at a point of $y=0$ is that there is a local smooth extension to a map on a neighborhood in $\Bbb R^2$. (This is definitely a confusing point at the beginning, and DoCarmo is not really dealing with it all super carefully. You might look at the introductory stuff in Guillemin and Pollack, together with the proof that boundary points of a manifold with boundary are well-defined.)